# NSMutableArray from plist key values separated by comma

Tags: iphone, ios5, theos

I have a plist file that stores cached colors, it looks like this

```
<key>CachedColors</key>
<dict>
    <key>com.Halfbrick.Fruit</key>
    <string>0.00000,0.00000,0.00000</string>
    <key>com.apple.Preferences</key>
    <string>0.28824,0.37059,0.48235</string>
</dict>
```

what I want to do is use the 3 values to create a UIColor, the UIColor will change depending on the bundle id, the values are for Red, Green, and Blue

but I'd want the UIColor to change automatically if the bundle id changes, I'm using it as the background color for the banners, and say if I'm on the home screen and get a notification, the background is white, but if I open the Settings app I'd want it to change to the RGB value for com.apple.Preferences from the plist sort of how in iOS 6 the status bar background changes automatically when opening an app to match the UINavigationBar

I used:

```
SBApplication *frontApp = [(SpringBoard*)[UIApplication sharedApplication] _accessibilityFrontMostApplication];
NSDictionary *statusBarCachedColors = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/cc.tweak.statuscolor.plist"];
NSString *colorString = [statusBarCachedColors objectForKey:frontApp];
NSArray *components = [colorString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:[components[0] floatValue] green:[components[1] floatValue] blue:[components[2] floatValue] alpha:1.0];
```

I am developing for a jailbroken device

Answer (score 0):

After you pick up that string from the plist:

```
NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:[components[0] floatValue] green:[components[1] floatValue] blue:[components[2] floatValue] alpha:1];
```

... Or on older compiler

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:[[components objectAtIndex:0] floatValue]
                                 green:[[components objectAtIndex:1] floatValue]
                                  blue:[[components objectAtIndex:2] floatValue] alpha:1];
```

If the question includes something else, it's hard to follow the punctuation

Comment: after testing this I'm getting an error saying

    'NSArray' may not respond to '-floatValue'

Comment: I'll update my OP, do you need what I used to read the plist also?

Comment: The warning you're getting is odd... What version of xCode are you using? perhaps it's not taking the array subscript notation?

Comment: Also, add a breakpoint and print what the components array looks like (po components, in the debugger console)

Comment: I'm not using Xcode, I'm using Theos which is a development environment for jailbroken devices, so there isn't a debugger console

Comment: your compiler might be old, let me update the response to cover for that

Comment: No problem, check that out

Comment: it did compile that time, I'm not sure if it's reading the values and changing and everything though, its supposed to change to the color corresponding to the topmost application, but it just stays black

Comment: what code are you using to change the tint? I'm only reading the values into the color, but not using it for anything

Comment: [self setBackgroundColor:tintColor];

Comment: but its in the initWithItem instance, it should at least update with every call to it correct? I'm hooking SBBannerView, shouldn't it check every time there is a new Notification?